# Use Winapi Sendmessage to retrieve a value from the message's recipient

Tags: winapi, message

Given two applications, A and B, B needs to get value from A in a synchronous way.

In other words, taking the object model for inspiration, application B wants to do some kind of `myVar = A.getValue()` and continue its execution using myVar in the rest of the code.

I have the handle of application A's main form and i know how to send message to it with `SendMessage()`. This function waits for the message to be proceed and then return an integer that is the result of the execution. But i don't know how to use this mechanism so that B gets back some complex data structure (string or data record).

It seems to me that using the SendMessage return value is not a good idea for many reasons, so is there a way  to do that?

It has to be done through Windows Messages (i already know how to do it through pipes and sockets).

Thank you!

*PS: i work with Delphi but that has no importance here, unless you are able to give examples in Delphi to illustrate your answer :)*

Comment: To whoever downvoted the question, please be more constructive and explain how it was not worth a question on stackoverflow. Or help me improve the text. Be brave :)

Answer (score 1):

The return value of a message is an `LRESULT`, that is a pointer sized value. If what you wish to return fits in such a value, that would be the clean way to proceed. Otherwise you need something else.

You say that you must use Windows messages, and that you are sending these messages between different processes. Given those constraints, there is exactly one solution, namely `WM_COPYDATA`. That is the only Windows message which can marshal custom data across a process boundary.

So the procedure is as follows:

1. Send a message from process B to process A. Include in that message a window handle from process B.
2. When process A receives the message, it must send a `WM_COPYDATA` to the window handle that was sent in stage 1.
3. Process B can then receive and process the message sent in stage 2.

Note that the `WM_COPYDATA` message is sent from process A to process B whilst process A is handling the original message. This means that the `WM_COPYDATA` is received and processed by process B, before the original message from B to A returns. This can be somewhat confusing, but you did state that you wanted to do this entirely with Windows messages.

Comment: You should take care to NOT perform step 1 from the main UI thread of process A to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: then who is going to process that WM_COPYDATA message?

Comment: The main thread of process A will do that, assuming that the window supplied is owned by that thread. There's no prospect of deadlocks because `SendMessage` in process A will still dispatch messages whilst it is waiting for process B to return from that message. Again, this is quite routine.

Comment: Hi David, i think you inverted A and B (because B wants to do `A.getValue()`) but that doesn't change the logic. However, i'm not sure how your solution match another of the constraints: when B retrieves value from A, the return must be immediate, hanging the code execution while getting the value. In your solution, once B have sent the initial message, what should B do? An infinite loop waiting for A to send WM_COPYDATA?

Comment: There's no looping. Send a message from B to A, and wait for it to return. When A receives the message it sends WM_COPYDATA to B. When A finishes, it returns control to B which has already received and processed the WM_COPYDATA.

Comment: Interesting, i'll try to implement that ping-pong messages, i didn't think that B can process the WM_COPYDATA while waiting in the procedure that called SendMessage.

Comment: @Ninj - that is what confused me. David, I have to withdraw my warning: apparently, the WndProc is re-entrant. You broke something in my head :)

Comment: `SendMessage` blocks waiting for the other process to signal that it has completed processing the message from stage 1. But whilst blocking it also dispatches incoming messages.

Comment: @VladFeinstein It's not so much that WndProc is re-entrant, which it is. It's more that `SendMessage` dispatches. The concept of *dispatching messages* is an important one.

Comment: Isn't it only that SendMessage doesn't block the thread execution, whilst leting the message queue be treated?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "SendMessages dispatches". While the message procedure called by SendMessage isn't finished, SendMessage does not return, right? But how is SendMessage Dispatching anything? The main application thread is dispatching, isn't it?

Comment: `SendMessage` is blocking for the recipient to finish processing the message. It waits on a synchronization object until the recipient signals that it has completed. But, whilst waiting on that synchronization object it can also wake up if messages are sent to the waiting thread. And then call the appropriate window procedure. That all happens inside the code for `SendMessage`. You can see all of this by implementing the concept in the answer, and then looking at the call stack when you are handling `WM_COPYDATA`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by one of your processes performing VirtualAllocEx() to allocate memory in another process and then use Read/WriteProcessMemory to copy data there.

Comment: Hi Vlad, i'm goign to dig into VirtualAllocEx() to see if i can find how to use it in my case. I'll come back here with results. Thank you